# the including of elf.h for projects and its significance

Tags: c

I often see this file is included in many projects.

Is this mostly for Unix, Linux, MacOS applications?

and which c files would use this elf.h file?

Comment: Seriously, for this basic question you would do some googling...

Comment: Third google link: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html

Answer (score 3):

`elf.h` is used for parsing and processing ELF files. You'll probably never see this on Windows because Windows does not use ELF files (it uses PE - Portable Executable - instead). OS X uses Mach-O, so `elf.h` isn't that common on OS X either (it doesn't ship as part of the default headers, for example). ELF format is primarily seen on Linux, where it is used for almost all binary executable files, from shared objects to executables.